# 'module' object has no attribute 'FieldStorage'

Tags: python, cgi

It doesn't make sense to me, because the code is very simple and "FieldStorage" exist in documentation.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print 'Content-type: text/html'
print
import cgi

def Main():
    form = cgi.FieldStorage()
    print '<html>'
    print '<body>'
    print 'ola'
    print '</body>'
    print '</html>'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Do you have a local file called `cgi.py` by any chance? That's being imported, instead of the standard library module.

Comment: @Luiz Use `print cgi.__file__` to find out

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same problem with a file named io.py.  That suggests there are other standard module names to avoid when naming your own .py files.  Once I changed the file (and got rid of the cached io.pyc file that got generated in an earlier run) the code behaved more normally.